# What does string + int perform in C?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I can't figure out this expression:

```
str + n
```

where `char str[STRING_LENGTH]` and `int n`.

I have worked a lot in Java and was assuming till now that it's concatenation of string and integer, which I doubt now.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 11):

It's pointer arithmetic. For instance:

```
char* str = "hello";
printf("%s\n", str + 2);
```

Output: `llo`. Because `str + 2` point to 2 elements after `str`, thus the first `l`.

Answer (score 7):

`str` can be regarded as pointing to the memory address associated with a character sequence of length STRING_LENGTH. As such, *c pointer arithmetic* is being exploited in your statement `str + n`. What is is doing is pointing to the memory address of the `n`<sup>th</sup> character in the character sequence.

Answer (score 4):

Yes ans of @Yu Hao and @Bathsheba are correct.
But if you want to do the concatenation, you can go as following code snippet.

```
char string[]="hello";
int number=4;
char cated_string[SIZE_CATED_STRING];
sprintf(cated_string,"%s%d",string,number);
printf("%s",cated_string);
```

Happy Coding.